# Exercises to reduce waist width

Tags: exercise, training

I am on the upper limit of large in terms of weight (70kg). I'm not short (about 179cm)  My shoulders are wide compared to my stomach width. The only problem is, after my body curves in from the shoulders to my stomach, it curves out at my waist again. It is not fat that makes my waist appear wide, because when I feel it, it seems like there is only bones here. I work out regularly, but I cannot shake off this overweight appearance because the width of my waist is as much as my shoulders. Because of this, my shirts take the width of my waist and my body appears to be a fat block. I understand it is impossible to alter my bone structure with exercise, but I am wondering if there are any exercises to reduce the width of my waist since it does look unnatural.

PS -- the width of my weight is about 100 cm.

Comment: Sorry, but what you describe sounds like a "spare  tire".  What is your age and activity level?

Answer (score 3):

If all you said is true and you just have a wide pelvis, and it's definitely not fat, I'd say there's not much you can do about that. Like you said, you cant alter bone structure with exercise.

I would say, however, given your height, you could probably pack on some more muscle so you fill out more evenly. You can probably gain like 5-10 kgs of muscle and still be within a normal weight range for your height so your body looks more balanced.

I think this may be the only way to alter how your waist and body "looks" with exercise.